# Let $A\subseteq(X,d)$. Show that $\operatorname{diam}(A)$ is finite and that $\exists x,y \in A$ such that $\operatorname{diam}(A)=d(x,y)$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, compactness

Let $A\subseteq (X,d)$ be a compact subset of $X$. Show that $\operatorname{diam}(A)$ is finite and that $\exists x,y \in A$ such that $\operatorname{diam}(A)=d(x,y)$

As $A$ is compact, so $A$ is bounded (and closed). So that $\operatorname{diam}(A)$ is finite.

How can I show the other part?

Comment: What do you know about $X$ as a topological space, beyond the fact that it is a metric space?

Comment: @Prototank Not much. But I know that $A$ is totally bounded. I can get the result from the definition of total bounded ness, but problem is my professor uses a different definition for total boundedness of a subset of metric space. In his definition, the centre of balls lies in $X$ and might not lie in $Y$

Comment: You have used the fact that $A$ is bounded to show that $A$ has a finite diameter. Now use the definition of diameter and the closure of $A$ to show that $x$ and $y$ must exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A$ be a compact subset of a metric space $X$. Then $A\times A\subset X\times X$ is also compact. In particular, $d:X\times X\to \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ is a continuous function. The extreme value theorem gives that $d(A\times A)$ is also compact. Do you see what to do from here?